Would cuiviëquendion be the proper translation of the awakening of the Elves?
Would cuiviëquendion be the proper translation of the awakening of the Elves ? As far as I understand cuivië means awakening and quendion is the genetive adjective associated to Quendi which literally means "the elves". As far as I see, cuiviëquendion is not used in Cuivienyarna nor anywhere else in Tolkien's legendarium.

I would make it two words, cuivie quendion, or else put the head noun last, quendacuivie.  Compare lasselanta (attested in the Appendices), ‘leaf-fall’, which could otherwise be something like lanta lassion.

@AntonSherwood Quendacuivie looks suspicious. I think it would be just Quendecuivie (cf. Quendelie).

They work better as separate words: cuivie quendion. I've tried to find a compound of the form noun + noun-gen, so far there is only Nan-tasarion "Vale of Willows".
One big reason to avoid it: It would be awkward to decline cuiviequendion. For example, "the account of the awakening of the Elves" would have to be quenta cuivieo quendion, much unlikely quenta cuiviequendiono - genitive ending upon genitive ending.
If you need a compound word, I think quendecuivie will do.
BTW, Quendion isn't technically adjective, it's the genitive plural case of quende. The adjective would be quenderinwa, which is actually declined like adjectives.
